# Summarise proportions of character values across columns in table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

In this kind of data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
     w1 = c("A","A","B","C","A"),
     w2 = c("C","A","A","C","C"),
     w3 = c("C","A","B","C","B")
   )
```

I need to calculate across all columns the within-column proportions of the character values. Interestingly, the following code works with the large actual data set but throws an error with the above toy data:

```
df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~prop.table(table(.))*100))
```

What I'm looking for is a data frame with exact proportions of all values in each column plus a column indicating the values:

```
       w1  w2  w3
1  A   60  40  20
2  B   20   0  40
3  C   20  60  40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround using `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, everything()) |> 
    count(value, name) |>
    mutate(n = n / sum(n) * 100, .by = name) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try `table` + `stack` like below

```
> proportions(table(stack(df)), 2) * 100
      ind
values w1 w2 w3
     A 60 40 20
     B 20  0 40
     C 20 60 40
```

Comment: How would this work as part of the pipe? And I misleadingly wrote I want a table; I've corrected this to 'data frame'.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann you can do `as.data.frame(proportions(table(stack(df)), 2) * 100) |> pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = Freq)`

Answer (score 4):

The error comes from the fact that you have one column with only two distinct values (`w2`), thus you create a column of length 2 while the others have length 3:

```
Error in names(dots)[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Convert all your columns to `factor` first, to make sure that all columns have the same levels (and `table` will account for even the empty ones), and then apply `reframe` (`summarise` is slowly deprecated in favor of `reframe` when multiple rows are outputted):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("w"), \(x) factor(x, levels = unique(df$w1)))) %>% 
  reframe(across(everything(), \(x) c(prop.table(table(x))*100))) %>% 
  mutate(value = unique(df$w1), .before = 1)

#   value w1 w2 w3
# 1     A 60 40 20
# 2     B 20  0 40
# 3     C 20 60 40
```

Comment: Good point! or `c`

Comment: this is very pretty!! My favourite :)

Comment: I got that error too, while using reframe, but I wasn't able to make heads or tails of it - not super descriptive ‍